# How to calculate $ \sum_{n=1}^{15}n(n!) = ? $

Tags: summation

In a contest between me and my friend, i was able to solve all the questions till he stumped me at this one.

$ \sum_{n=1}^{15}n(n!) =?$

The only thing I could think of how to pursue is

> $n(n+1)! = n^2(n-1)!$.

Preferably give hints, so i can try it again.

Edit: After getting the solution the next second I posted the question, I would further extend the question to how you guys got the idea, of this fairly simple looking but well thought out solution. Is it all practice or you might get some hint always from the question???

Comment: Hint: each term is nearly $(n+1)n!$

Comment: You can rephrase the 'Edit' section to "how does the human mind works?". I don't think you'll get a good enough answer here (or anywhere else for that matter, unless you can time-travel to the future).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$
n\cdot n! = (n+1-1)n!=(n+1)n!-n! = (n+1)!-n!
$$

Comment: Thnx, though it was the whole solution.+1

Comment: Plz answer the edit too, thnx!

Comment: I just remembered the memory years ago that $\sum n\cdot n!$ can be represented as telescopic series.

Comment: This reminds me of an exercise back at the University which was similar and involved a telescopic series, too. I was so puzzled until I saw the solution. My recommendation to the OP: Just try to memorize it and use it in the right places. No worries, this is the normal process of learning and getting more and more experienced.

Answer (score 4):

$$n\cdot n! = n\cdot n\cdot (n-1)! = n^2\cdot (n-1)!$$

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{N} n\cdot n! = (1 + N)! - 1 $$

Comment: I got till here but after it??

Comment: Sry bt i still am nt able to understnd, a bit more explaination plzz.

Comment: How do you get $\sum_{n = 1}^{N} n^2\cdot (n-1)! = (1 + N)! - 1$???

Comment: @fleablood I'll write the proof later! I'm on the bus now :D

Comment: No, rush.  (after all there are other solutions) I just think this needs clarification in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use perturbation method from 'Concrete Mathematics':
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k! \to S_n + (n+1)! = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k! + (n+1)! = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(k+1)! + 1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k!k + \sum_{k=1}^{n} k! + 1
$$
Now do some very simple algebra and get the result. Then plug in your $n=15$.

Comment: Sry, am a noob bt plz explain a bit more.

Comment: explain what exactly?

Comment: The steps from strtng. Thnx :)

Comment: 1) Define $S_n$, 2) Add the next term on both sides, 3) Manipulate RHS with sm algebra, 4)Get the result

Comment: 3rd step i dnt get it.

Comment: $1+ 2! + \ldots n! + (n+1)! = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)! + 1$

Comment: Thnx n now the last step.

Comment: Use the property of factorial and cancel out the $S_n$ term

Comment: Uhm, sorry but this does not strike me as a good answer. It is a little involved, the first steps being completely useless: the point of the question is just the last step, which is not clearly motivated.

Comment: I'm practically devastated

Comment: This does seem a bit obscure and hiding a really good answer.  I think it'd be more direct and clearer as: $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k! = \sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)! =\sum_{k=0}^nk!(k+1) = \sum_{k=0}^n(k!k+k!) = \sum_{k=0}^nk!k + \sum_{k=0}^nk! = \sum_{k=1}^nk!k + \sum_{k=1}^nk! + 1 \implies  \sum_{k=1}^nk!k = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k! - \sum_{k=1}^nk! - 1 = (n+1)! - 1$.

Comment: This approach is from Concrete Mathematics and is totally legitimate